# Como corrijo el sgt error?

Tags: java, mysql

como están?, bueno, lo que me pasa básicamente es que estoy creando el sgt método para una secuencia SQL.

```
public boolean insertventas() {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO ventas (id_venta, venFechaventa, venId_cliente, venIdadministrador, venTotalventa) VALUES (NULL, '" + vent() + "', '" + clasu.getId_usuarios() + "', '1', '" + pnlProductos.totall + "')";
    try {
        
        con = cn.getConnection();
        ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        return true;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LogicaSql.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return false;
    }
}
```

vent(), es el metodo que uso para traer la fecha, clasu.getId_usuarios() es el metodo que hice para q se muestre el id del usuario que ha iniciado sesion, y pnlProductos.totall es donde pongo el total de la venta q ha realizado ese usuario por medio de una variable estatica.
(Esa sentencia del insert ya la probe por aparte en phpMyAdmin y si esta buena).
aqui es donde llamo al metodo insertventas().

```
private void rSButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    LogicaSql insert = new LogicaSql();
    insert.insertventas();
    numfac.setText("");
    int fila = jTable2.getRowCount();
    for (int i = fila - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        modelo2.removeRow(i);
    }
    totalventa.setText("");
    p.setTotall(0);
}
```

desde el numfac.setText para abajo esta bueno, lo que pasa es en el llamado(creería yo), me sale este error.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Clase.LogicaSql.insertventas(LogicaSql.java:211)
at panelesClientes.pnlCompras.rSButton1ActionPerformed(pnlCompras.java:226)
at panelesClientes.pnlCompras.access$000(pnlCompras.java:24)
at panelesClientes.pnlCompras$1.actionPerformed(pnlCompras.java:140)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

alguien sabe porque me sale?, gracias de antemano por sus respuestas

Comment: *java.lang.NullPointerException
at Clase.LogicaSql.insertventas(LogicaSql.java:211)* -> Tienes un objeto en el archivo LogicaSQL, la línea 211 sobre el cual estás intentando invocar un método... pero el objeto es NULL.

Comment: ese seria la declaracion del String sql = (sentencia sql), osea que no le esta llegando nada a ese objeto? y si no le esta llegando nada, como puedo solucionarlo y la sentencia del insert ya la probe por aparte y funciona correctamente

Comment: ¿A qué te referís con "ya la probé por aparte"? Adicionalmente: estás haciendo un `preparedStatement` pero estás concatenando los parámetros...

Comment: No le está llegando nada a ese objeto no, en esa línea utilizas al menos dos objetos que yo vea: `pnlProductos` y `clasu`, pues el propio error te está diciendo que uno de ellos no es un objeto, si no un `null`.

Comment: No concatenes strings para componer SQL, a menos que estés usando Dynamic SQL (no es el caso). Tu código es altamente vulnerable a SQL Injection.